# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context solution

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

So for school I got the task to make an API so you can login on a database and after you logged in, you can access some data. To login, we're using AspNetUsers made from another project that uses MVC. My current code:

### AccountController.cs

```
namespace Klantenzone.API2.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private AuthRepository _repo = null;

        public AccountController()
        {
            _repo = new AuthRepository();
        }
    }
}
```

### WebApiConfig.cs

```
namespace Klantenzone.API2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var jsonFomatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFomatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

### AuthContext.cs

```
namespace Klantenzone.API2.Internal
{
    public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AuthContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### AuthRepository.cs

```
namespace Klantenzone.API2.Internal
{
    public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private AuthContext _ctx;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AuthRepository()
        {
            _ctx = new AuthContext();
        }

        public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_ctx);
            _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            //_userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_ctx));
            //IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
            ApplicationUser user2 = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
            return user2;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _ctx.Dispose();
            _userManager.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

### BeginAPI.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("APIOwin",typeof(Klantenzone.API2.Internal.BeginAPI))]
namespace Klantenzone.API2.Internal
{
    public class BeginAPI
    {


        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            //Token generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

However, every time I try to log in using this API (I use Postman to test it), I get the error: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context (in AuthRepository). So far I've done all I could. The connectionstring is not based on the edmx of the database. I'm using ApplicationUser because the AspNetUsers tables were made from MVC. Yet it still doesn't want to work. Anyone who could help me out? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: My application follows pretty much the same pattern as above and I have exactly the same error. I have searched Google and Stackoverflow but can't get a solution. Has anyone solved this?